# Is it possible to remote debug Windows 8 with VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I am using VS 2010 and trying to remote debug a Window 8 machine. I can't find a VS 2010 remote debugger stub compatible with Window 8. Is it possible to remote debug Window 8 with VS 2010 or must I upgrade to VS 2012?

Comment: What type of project are you remote debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 applications can only be created/debugged with Visual Studio 2012 or newer.

John Wiese
Microsoft - Sr. Technical Evangelist
jwiese@microsoft.com
@johnwiese

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible.

Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Remote Debugger Tools on the Windows 8 client
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=475

Each time you open msvsmon.exe, it tries to use Windows Authentication. You need to disable this when opening, with this command;
msvsmon.exe /noauth /nosecuritywarn

It's related to this issue;
[Remote debugging in visual studio: remote debugger does not support this edition of windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886383/remote-debugging-in-visual-studio)

Here's a screenshot
[image]